# ImportError for django.contrib.markup

Tags: django

I am trying to enable markup app in django and added 'django.contrib.markup' to INSTALLED APPS and in my model i import it as "import markdown".. but when i go to db and try to add something, i always get importerror. i guess iit must be about app installation issue or am i missing something?

this is how i do it in models.py:

```
class Entry(...)
title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=255)
slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug")
content_markdown = models.TextField(verbose_name="Markdown Content",
                                    help_text="Use Markdown syntax here.")
content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Page content as HTML", 
                           help_text="You don't have to touch here.", 
                           blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Published")
author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Author")

def save(self):
    import markdown
    self.content = markdown.markdown(self.content_markdown)
    super(Page, self).save()
```

great thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

I think that adding the `django.contrib.markup` app to your project gives you the ability to `{% load markup %}` in your templates (see [the official Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/#markup)). I think you'll still need to install [Markdown from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) to use it (`sudo easy_install Markdown`).

Comment: It's {% load markup %}, when then allows you to use the "|markdown" filter (among others). Otherwise this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to make sure you have [Markdown for Python](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) installed on your Python path for this to work.

Comment: easy_install installs markdown to /home/[username]/bin directory. i use export PYTHONPATH=/home/[username]/bin/markdown to update my pythonpath. but i still get the No module named markdown error. what is that about then?

Comment: Are you using the development server or a production server? 

What happens if you try to import markdown from a django shell?

Comment: i am using production server. by django shell, it works.

i don't know why it didn't work with easy_install, but later on i installed the markdown lib downloading source code and setup it manually, then set the pythonpath again. then it worked.. thanks for help;)

Comment: It's possible the user that was running your production server (e.g. apache) didn't have markdown on the python path it was using.

Comment: Well, actually later on i found that the markdown lib was installed by easy_install did not install a markdown.py file in my host. It just installed a markdown file without any file extension. Because in many website I saw PYTHONPATH was referring to markdown.py file, I tried to install it manually. That's how I made it works;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem as you had today. Your solution works, compile it from the source rather than using easy_install. But I still not satisfied with that answer, why easy_install not work? We know django shell server works, but not production server right? The solution is very simple, you must restart apache. I don't know why, but after you run service restart httpd (on centos), then the problem is gone.